# Creating same circles with PointsMaterial and CircleGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to create circles in two different ways:

- With a circle sprite, then draw it with Points and PointsMaterial
- With basic circle buffer geometries

However, I cannot make them match together because of PointsMaterial size.

```js
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

const fov = 40;
const near = 10;
const far = 200;

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, width / height, near, far);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const circle_sprite = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
  'https://fastforwardlabs.github.io/visualization_assets/circle-sprite.png'
);

const factor = 280;

const positions = [
  { x: 100, y: -5 },
  { x: 6, y: 50 }
];

const circleRadius = 20;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xefefef);

/* First method */
const pointsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

const colors = [];
for (const position of positions) {
  // Set vector coordinates from data
  const vertex = new THREE.Vector3(position.x, position.y, 0);
  pointsGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
  const color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
  colors.push(color);
}
pointsGeometry.colors = colors;

const pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: (factor * circleRadius) / fov,
  sizeAttenuation: false,
  vertexColors: true,
  map: circle_sprite,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.5
});

const firstPoints = new THREE.Points(pointsGeometry, pointsMaterial);
scene.add(firstPoints);

/* Second method */
const circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(circleRadius, 32);
const circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.5
});
positions.forEach((position) => {
  const circleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, circleMaterial);
  circleMesh.position.set(position.x, position.y, 0);
  scene.add(circleMesh);
});

/* Render loop */
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

camera.position.set(0, 0, far);
```

I try to find the factor variable value but I also discovered that width or height are involved in this factor.
How can I draw same circles with PointsMaterial?

Comment: PointsMaterial's size property is in pixels, regardless of viewport size. However, a mesh with `CircleGeometry` would be measured in world units, which shrinks when the viewport gets smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12150#issuecomment-327874431, you can compute the size of points.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(grid);

// geometry

var cGeom = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(1, 32);
var cMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "magenta"
});
var circle = new THREE.Mesh(cGeom, cMat);
circle.position.set(0, 3, 0);
scene.add(circle);

// points

var g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([new THREE.Vector3()]);
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.width = 128;
c.height = 128;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(64, 64, 64, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

var tex = new THREE.CanvasTexture(c);

var desiredSize = 2;
var pSize = desiredSize / Math.tan( THREE.Math.degToRad( camera.fov / 2 ) );

var m = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: pSize,
  color: "aqua",
  map: tex,
  alphaMap: tex,
  alphaTest: 0.5
});
var p = new THREE.Points(g, m);
scene.add(p);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly the formula I needed!

Comment: @Charlie You're welcome :) But all kudos to WestLangley :)